# When i go with 5 users 5 iteration i am facing timeout exception and Unhandled alert exception in selenium webdriver sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Totally i have 10 data only all data are valid values.

When i ran with 2 users 5 iteration i was not facing any kind of exception and errors but when i go with multiple users and iteration i am facing "Time out exception" and "unhandled alert error"

2. 2nd question is i have one alert. That is disappearing very fast i am not able get the alert text and switch the alert and also dismiss it

Could you please tell me how to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be the case your system under test gets overloaded and cannot properly handle "multiple users", it worth checking its logs and whether it has enough resources. You can do this using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics). Alternatively JMeter itself can become overloaded as browsers are very resource intensive. For example [Firefox 114](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/114.0/system-requirements/) needs 1 CPU core and 2 GB or RAM per instance so for 10 "users" you will need 11 CPU cores and 20 GB of RAM". So check whether JMeter load generator machine is capable of operating that many browsers and if it is not the case consider going for [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

   Moreover using Selenium for performance testing is not recommended either by [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

   > Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.

   or by [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) developers.

   > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.
2. There is a special [condition](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#alertIsPresent()) to check whether the alert is present which you can use in the [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait). If the alert goes away before your code can detect it and get its text - see recommendation for checking resources of your JMeter load generator and distributed testing.